# Can datajs read non-odata services

Tags: wcf, sharepoint, datajs

I have a wcf service hosted in sharepoint that retunrs a list of objects. Its a not a wcf data service, just a 'regular' wcf data service.

Can data js read dta from a 'regular' wcf data service?

Answer (score 1):

In short - no. datajs can only consume OData formatted payloads.